# Change cURL configuration

Tags: php, curl

I have PHP and cURL installed on my local webserver, now i want to change its default configuration. phpinfo() returns details as below

```
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.35.0
Age 3
Features
AsynchDNS   Yes
CharConv    No
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   Yes
IDN Yes
IPv6    Yes
krb4    No
Largefile   Yes
libz    Yes
NTLM    Yes
NTLMWB  Yes
SPNEGO  No
SSL Yes
SSPI    No
TLS-SRP Yes
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host    x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
SSL Version OpenSSL/1.0.1f
ZLib Version    1.2.8
```

Is it possible to change a cURL settings?
the three item below i want to change.

```
SPNEGO  : No
TLS-SRP :   Yes
GSS-Negotiate    : Yes
```

how can i change this values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996050/how-to-enable-features-for-php-curl

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659627/php-how-to-use-curl-with-kerberos